# Can't figure out regex match, how far off am I?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Super basic question (which I admittedly probably shouldn't post on SO, but here goes): I'm trying to create a regex to match (and exclude from a function) all links that begins with `//images`, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work.

Right now I have:

```
$('a:not([href^=/\/\images])').each(function(){
```

But since that clearly isn't correct, and I really don't know where to begin looking to set it straight, I'm asking for advice. I'm used to escaping strings etc., but this seems to be quite different(?).

Also, I tried using http://regexr.com/ and https://txt2re.com/ (didn't even understand how to work the latter...) but honestly I feel like I have no clue as to what to put where at this point since I'm basically guessing.

Again, sorry for posting such a basic question, but right now this is all gibberish to me, sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has little to do with jQuery or regular expressions. What you're asking about is a CSS selector which has different behaviour altogether. Your problem is with `/\/\` vs `\/\/`.

Note that you don't actually have to escape the slashes here.

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('a:not([href^="//images"])');
console.log(images);
```

```html
<a href="//images/cat.jpg">cat</a>
<a href="//images/dog.jpg">dog</a>
<a href="/images/fox.jpg">fox</a>
<a href="/images/bear.jpg">fox</a>
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer, appreciate it! I see now that I need to read up on this to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

That is not regex, that is JQuery selector. This is how you can match them:

```
   $("a:not([href^='//images'])").each(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('href'));

    });
```

Comment: Didn't know you could skip escaping slashes here. Cool.

Comment: Oh, I was really out and about then. Need too read up on this stuff, no doubt. Thanks for setting me straight!

Comment: Yes, and I see now that I wrote "JQuery selector" while @naomik told "CSS selector" which is more correct, but anyway it's don't have nothing with regular expression.